# Vector of class type error

Tags: c++, class, object, vector, stl

So I am trying to push_back an int to my vector but I keep getting a lot of errors in doing so. I know this would work if I just made my vector into "vector< int >" type but I want to know how to do this with a vector of objects such as what I have below.

What can I do to fix this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class ClassName
{
public:
    ClassName()
    {}

    ~ClassName()
    {}

    void AddInt(int num)
    {
        m_Vector.push_back(num);
    }


private:
    vector<ClassName> m_Vector;
};

int main()
{
// Create our class an add a few ints
   ClassName obj;
   obj.AddInt(32);
   obj.AddInt(56);
   obj.AddInt(21);


return 0;
}
```

errors that I get:

> [Error] no matching function for call to
>   'std::vector::push_back(int&)'
>
> [Note] void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&)
>   [with _Tp = ClassName; _Alloc = std::allocator;
>   std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = ClassName]

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do. How do you intend to convert an integer into a `ClassName`?

Comment: You need a constructor `ClassName(int)` if you want to rely on implicit type conversion.

Comment: So then how should I implement this with a ClassName(int) ? Or whats the work around this?

Comment: Remove the c'tor and d'tor definitions.  The compiler will generate them correctly for you, and whenever you explicitly define the d'tor, it implicitly deletes the copy constructor, which you need.

Comment: @Lex It seems you are new to the basics, so I would like to ask you exactly what `ClassName` is supposed to represent.  A class should describe something tangible and obvious.  In your example, it's not clear whether it is supposed to describe some sort of tree structure, or if it is simply meant to hold a bunch of integers.

Comment: its for a implementing a Graph but wanted to keep it simple, so I wrote a small example. I just need a way to push to the vector object so then I can compare the result with another vertex.

Answer (score 0):

As @paddy has pointed out in the comments, you will need a constructor that will implicitly convert to the type for you. You are able to do this by declaring a constructor that takes a **single** parameter of the type you wish to convert to:

```
class MyInt
{
public:
    MyInt(int i) : number(i) {}
private:
    int number;
};
```

This can be used as follows:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<MyInt> numbers;
    numbers.push_back(1);
    numbers.push_back(42);
    numbers.push_back(MyInt(4)); // explicit conversion
}
```

However, the main problem you will face with your current design, even after adding a constructor is that you are declaring an object of type `ClassName` inside `ClassName`, which you are unable to do.

The only way to get this to work is to declare a pointer to the type:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector< std::unique_ptr<MyInt> > v;
    v.push_back(std::make_unique<MyInt>(42));
}
```

Which would make your class:

```
class MyInt
{
public:
    MyInt() : n(0) {}
    MyInt(int i) : n(i) {}
    void AddInt(int i)
    {
        numbers.push_back(std::make_unique<MyInt>(i));
    }
private:
    int n;
    std::vector< std::unique_ptr<MyInt> > numbers;
};
```

But that doesn't make sense. I can't see why you'd want class `ClassName` have a vector of `ClassName` that store numbers; however, this would work fine if you have a class that held an `int` (see my previous example of `MyInt`) and then had an `MyIntContainer` class, which had the following:

```
class MyIntContainer
{
public:
    void AddInt(int i)
    {
        numbers.push_back(i);
    }
private:
    std::vector<MyInt> numbers;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Standard library containers must be instantiated with complete types.

So it is not possible for a class to contain a `std::vector` of itself. The line `vector<ClassName> m_Vector` causes undefined behaviour (no diagnostic requied).

Your options are:

- use a non-standard container that allows incomplete types, e.g. a Boost container
- use a vector of a different type you've already defined
- use a vector of smart pointers
- a different way of doing what you're trying to do

Based on your sample code it seems like you might want `vector<int>` instead of `vector<ClassName>`, which would avoid this problem.

Usually it doesn't make semantic sense for a class to contain a container of itself (obviously, most such instances would have to contain an empty container otherwise you'll use infinite memory).